# How to auto deploy symfony app with gitlab-ci in private server?

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab-ci

I recently discovered gitlab-ci in order to automate a lot of things for my development.
So I managed to set up a "test" stage, which allows me to run my unit tests.
Perfect, everything works well.
Now I'm blocked: I would like to be able to deploy automatically on my dedicated server when I validate the MR.
In the gitlab documentation, the example is above AWS, or makefile but without example!

Ideas of how to do it on a private dedicated server?

For information, it is a PHP project Symfony 3. In any case, I would like a deployment quite common: pull the master branch, execute a composer install and restore the rights of the various folders.
My application is under Docker, so I have to not only be able to access my remote server, but also access my container that manages my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My deployment step looks like this - maybe it gives you some ideas:

```
build:app:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  variables:
    SYMFONY_ENV: "prod"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - export IMAGE_TAG=$(echo -en $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME | tr -c '[:alnum:]_.-' '-')
  script:
    - docker run --rm --name composerinstall -v "$PWD":/var/www/app -w /var/www/app composer:1.4 install --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs --no-suggest --no-progress --no-scripts --prefer-dist
    - cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG"
  only: [develop]
  dependencies:
    - test:php7.0
    - test:php7.1
  tags:
    - autoscale


deploy:staging:
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: "1"
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://123.123.123.123:2376"
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "/home/gitlab-runner/.docker/machine/machines/dockerhost1"
    DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME: "dockerhost1"
    SYMFONY_ENV: prod
    MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD: "$MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD"
    SECRET_TOKEN: "$SECRET_TOKEN"
    COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: "myproject_staging"
    COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR: "$(pwd -P)/.composer-cache"
    ASSET_VERSION: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}
  before_script:
    - export BRANCH=$(echo -en $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME | tr -c '[:alnum:]_.-' '-')
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull --parallel
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate app
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml restart php
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec -T --user www-data php composer install --no-dev --no-suggest --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec -T --user www-data php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://staging.myproject.com
  only: [develop]
  dependencies:
    - build:app
  tags:
    - deploy
```

The Dockerfile for the build step is now only:

```
FROM busybox:latest

COPY . /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/vendor && \
    mkdir -p /app/mediastore  && \
    mkdir -p /app/web/imagecache  && \
    mkdir -p /.composer && \
    chown 33:33 -R /.composer && \
    chown 33:33 -R /app/var && \
    chown 33:33 -R /app/mediastore && \
    chown 33:33 -R /app/vendor && \
    chown 33:33 -R /app/web/imagecache && \
    chown 33:33 /app/app/config/parameters.yml
```

To benefit of the env variables i have this in my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
  database_host:     '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
  database_port:     '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
  database_name:     '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
  database_user:     '%env(DATABASE_USERNAME)%'
  database_password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'    
  secret:            '%env(SECRET_TOKEN)%'    
  asset_version:     '%env(ASSET_VERSION)%'

  # Default fallback if env not set
  env(DATABASE_HOST):     127.0.0.1
  env(DATABASE_PORT):     ~
  env(DATABASE_NAME):     symfony
  env(DATABASE_USERNAME): root
  env(DATABASE_PASSWORD): ~    
  env(ASSET_VERSION): ~
  env(SECRET_TOKEN): ~
```

And the Docker-Compose:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    database-volume:

services:
    app:
        image: "dockerhub.mydomain.com/mygroup/myproject:${BRANCH}"
        environment:
            BRANCH: develop
        tty: true
        restart: always

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - database-volume:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_USER: myuser
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        restart: always

    php:
        image: dockerhub.mydomain.com/docker/php/fpm:7.0
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        environment:
            DATABASE_HOST: "mysql"
            DATABASE_PORT: "3306"
            DATABASE_NAME: "mydatabase"
            DATABASE_USERNAME: "myuser"
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PROD_PASSWORD}"
            SECRET_TOKEN: "${SECRET_TOKEN}"
            SYMFONY_ENV: prod
        volumes_from:
            - app
        restart: always

    apache:
        image: dockerhub.mydomain.com/mygroup/myproject:apache
        volumes_from:
            - app
        environment:
            VIRTUAL_HOST: "staging.myproject.com,staging.myproject.eu"
        restart: always

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

dockerhub.mydomain.com is the given url for the docker registry built into gitlab.

Comment: Your gitlab-ci is very useful and helped me a lot for inspiration. Could you share the whole file though. I wonder how you implemented your tests and what images, are using to deploy to have docker-compose and what the prod configuration looks like. Thanks ! :)

Comment: if you make it as a blog post I am sure you will get a lot of traffic.

Comment: @YusufIbrahim you are right - its about time :) i started on it - multi article series - https://cwd.at/blog/2019-12-07_gitlabci-docker-php/

Answer (score 2):

Your sample is really nice! I don't use docker hub to host my dockerfile :/
But I found the solution for my use case!
In first, I add my private SSH key in a variable in my gitlab repository (I found this here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html). After that, I can connect to my host and execute remote command!
So my gitlab-ci.yml look like:

```
deploy:app:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://example.com
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh -t user@example.com 'cd ~/docker &&
        git pull origin master &&
        docker exec docker_engine_1 bash -c "
          ./bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f &&
          composer install &&
          chmod -R 777 var/cache/prod/
        "
      '
```

But your example give me some idea: use doctrine migration for example ...

Comment: as noted - i dont use dockerhub. i use gitlab built in docker registry. see http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/container_registry.html and http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/container_registry.html

Comment: hum i see, thanks for the links!
But i don't understand when you deploy your app in your server here ... Can you explain ?

Comment: application deployment is done via docker-compose. you see the env variables, in the deploy stage? i just recreate the app container on the target host. (`DOCKER_HOST`)

Comment: the runner is running on my main deployment host - which has access to all the servers i need to deploy to. and this runner is only used for deployment. (note the `tags` in the different stages)